# Computational Fluid Dynamics and C++

Tags: c++, genetic-algorithm, fluid-dynamics

I started to work on my graduation project and it’s about CFD and searching algorithms. My goal is creating 3d models randomly and with data from my own CFD program, optimizing them automatically using searching algorithms for creating an optimized car model. When I talked about my project with my professor, he told me to use C++. I will code CFD program with c++ so I need guidelines about how can I do it. I had ideas about a c++ program that will use other 3d engines(like creating a model and displaying it and its’ fluid movements in unity) but I don’t have any clue about how to do it.

**Questions**

- How can I create a 3d model just using codes.(Like giving it
  coordinates and it will create model)
- How can I display it using C++. When I run my program, I want to see 
  3d model and fluid’s movement

Any ideas/suggestions would be awesome.

Comment: That is a very advance topic. If you're trying to create a model from just pure c++ it is a daunting task. You can use APIs such as DirectX, OpenGL, Vulcan etc. to ease the process but it is still a daunting process. With 3D Models, you will have all of your vertices in some kind of primitive format such as triangle strips that would create a mesh to your model. That still isn't enough information because you'll probably need texture coordinates and will have to map them appropriately. Then there are normals for lighting. Unity is a good start, I'd suggest reading through their documentations.

Comment: wait, so you don't know C++? It usually takes about 10 years and several projects of C++ experience to write any decent source code. If this is your first C++ project, then it's highly likely it will be good for `rm -rf <project_dir>` only. As the CFD is complex topic enough, if you are well versed in the math behind, maybe you should team up with some good C++ programmer. But as you are asking about 3D model generation, it looks like you are not that deep even into the math stuff, so... makes me wonder, how many years you want to spend on this project, 5+ makes sense.

Comment: I recommend you search the internet for 3D libraries.  I suggest you try drawing a wireframe cube as your first or second project.  Focus on getting all the tools to work correctly.  Once the tools work correctly, the rest of the project becomes easier.

Comment: You don't need 10 years of programing to write a CFD code in C++. Nobody would ever graduate if they did. But you have some major open-source CFD software online like OpenFOAM. You also have major open source 2D and 3D mesh/grid generation software. The point is, as long as you're not looking into a specific method that was not coded yet, you should mostly rely on things that are already there, developed and well-established. There are more problems with CFD then coding, using other's good work gives you more time to focus on the 100 other issues.

Answer (score 0):

How long do you have? If you don't have a lot of time, then use an open source code such as OpenFOAM. If you have a licence, use a GUI point and click code like Ansys Fluent, CFX or Siemens StarCCM+. If you have time, look into FORTRAN - I find it's "friendlier" than C++.